# How to dump CST tree

Tags: python, dfa

I'm learning python, but when I print info when I debug code, but it's not convenient. I want to print CST, AST, ByteCode with iPython, write a python file, then print them, and then to read the code.

But, I can't dump the CST tree which will transform to AST, I know I can print CST tree by modifying python source code, but how to dump the CST tree in iPython just like dump AST with package.

```
1. get AST with ast package
2. get ByteCode with dis package
```

Comment: parser module  is ok, thanks Emily E Morehouse

Comment: but how to print more friendly?